# What is the best practice to remove duplicate items from an array in a reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers, react-context

I am new to working with reducers to store data and have stumbled across an issue. I currently have a list of checkboxes that when clicked dispatches an action to store them inside an array in my reducer. Currently, however, I can keep checking/unchecking and the same value will continue to be pushed to the array.

How can I prevent this from happening? Do I somehow filter out inside the reducer or in my handleChange event on the checkbox?

I have added a small snippet of my current code

Thanks!

```js
function handleCheckboxChange(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      checkboxContext.dispatch({
        type: 'SET_PROPERTY_TYPE',
        payload: { [e.target.name]: e.target.checked }
      });
    }
  }
  
  
 const FilterCheckbox = ({ name, value, handleChange, checkedItems }) => (
  <Label>
    <FilterInput
      type="checkbox"
      name={name}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      checked={checkedItems[name]}
    />
    {name}
  </Label>
);

export default FilterCheckbox;

// Sets the selected value...
 case 'SET_PROPERTY_TYPE':
      return {
        ...state,
        propertyType: [...state.propertyType, action.payload]
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could just filter your `state.propertyType` to remove any duplicates.

```
// Sets the selected value...
 case 'SET_PROPERTY_TYPE':
      return {
        ...state,
        propertyType: [
            ...state.propertyType.filter((value) => 
                 Object.keys(value)[0] !== Object.keys(action.payload)[0]), 
            action.payload
        ]
      };
```

You could also change your `state.propertyType` to an object to make things nicer:

```
  function handleCheckboxChange(e) {
    checkboxContext.dispatch({
      type: 'SET_PROPERTY_TYPE',
      payload: { [e.target.name]: e.target.checked }
    });
  }


 const FilterCheckbox = ({ name, value, handleChange, checkedItems }) => (
  <Label>
    <FilterInput
      type="checkbox"
      name={name}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      checked={checkedItems[name]}
    />
    {name}
  </Label>
);

export default FilterCheckbox;

// Sets the selected value...
 case 'SET_PROPERTY_TYPE':
      return {
        ...state,
        propertyType: {
          ...state.propertyType, 
          ...action.payload
        }
      };
```

You would also need to change how `FilterCheckbox` are mapped from the state.

Comment: Fabulous! You could also change the ```state.propertyType``` to be an object, then the code would be a little cleaner and no filtering would be needed

Comment: I've just noticed I also need to filter out the value if it is unchecked, as I was only running the dispatch on (e.target.checked), if I changed it to an object, this wouldn't work - would it?

Comment: I'll add an example with ```state.propertyType``` being an object

Comment: This however would not keep the order in which you clicked the checkboxes, which might not be ideal for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adam, how come I would need to change how it is mapped? Sorry I am quite new to it all!

Comment: Nevermind, because it's an array, duh! Thanks for your help Adam, really appreciate it!

Have a great day!

Comment: Mapping an object without any special effort usually doesn't end well :D I'm glad I could help!